# Is there a way to set different confidence thresholds for different classes using Detectron2?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

I am working on an object detection model for microscopic images. Some of my classes are very simple (feature wise), they are practically fancy lines. Some are more complicated objects. My problem is that I am getting a lot of False Positives for the simple classes, because anything that looks loke a line gets classified.

I am using the Detectron2 framework and I wonder if there is a way to set a higher confidence threshold for the simple classes?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I'm not expert in images, but I assume it's multiclass classification, right? In this case there's no way to do this directly, because the most likely class is predicted relatively to the others. However it might be worth trying a second stage specific for this class, which would use binary classification on the instances predicted positive in the 1st step to try to separate the FPs and TPs. Here it would be possible to change the threshold, but of course this will likely cause missing some TPs.

Comment: I'm doing multi-class object detection. Currently using faster-RCNN. I understand that I get the class prediction via softmax. I'm just not sure what to do with all the FPs. What do you mean by adding a second stage? I would want to train this along with the rest of the network. I thought of using weighted cross entropy to penalize the FPs for this class more.

Comment: This is multiclass, which means that you don't have a single positive class. I doubt that penalizing FPs in general would work, because the model might try to decrease FPs for the other classes, causing more FPs in the ones you're interested in. The balance FP/TP can only be tuned in binary classification, this is why I propose to add a second independent model which focuses only on the instances predicted for this particular class. This class is hard to predict anyway, but this way you could increase the threshold to decrease FPs. Note that these instances would be left with no prediction.

Comment: Cool, I will definitely try that! Thanks!